# Give URL to picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I have a picture box in my application which displays pictures. Now if user clicks the picture/picture box then he should be redirected to the hyperlink given for that particular image in picturebox.

Is it possible? If yes, then how , if no then what would be an alternative?

I am using C# (Windows development)

Let me know for any inputs from my side

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5713934/give-url-to-picturebox");
        }
```